# "Context cannot be resolved or is not a field" error in a timer in Android OpenCV application

Tags: android, opencv, timer

I'm trying to show the results of a timer implemented in following code in my Android OpenCV application:

```
case ImageManipulationsActivity.VIEW_MODE_MEDIAN:
capture.retrieve(mRgba, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA); 
if (mRgbaInnerWindow == null|| mGrayInnerWindow == null)
CreateAuxiliaryMats();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Imgproc.medianBlur(mRgbaInnerWindow, mIntermediateMat, 25);
Core.convertScaleAbs(mIntermediateMat, mIntermediateMat, 1./10, 0);
Core.convertScaleAbs(mIntermediateMat, mRgbaInnerWindow, 10, 0);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapse = end - start;
Toast.makeText(ImageManipulationsView.context.getActivity(), "" + elapse + "ms is used
to process", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I'm getting an error "Context cannot be resolved or is not a field" What am I doing wrong? Is my timer correct? How can I display the results of it?

@Sahil Mahajan Mj
Now I have an error in line:

```
Toast.makeText(ImageManipulationsView.this, "" + elapse + "ms is used to",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

from the code I've pasted in the beginning. The error is "The method makeText in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments"
If it helps, my app is a modification of Image-manipulations sample from OpenCV4Android package

@Blundell
I've changed the context variable to public and the whole app crashes when I choose medianBlur from my app menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about this,

```
Toast.makeText(ImageManipulationsView.context.getActivity(), "" + elapse + "ms is used
to process", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You just need to the Activity's Context like this,

```
ImageManipulationsView.this
```

If there is some other error, you need to post the code, where actually the error is. Only then I can edit my answer.

Comment: Now I have another error in the same line. I have updated my question with it.

Comment: @user1929549 what is **ImageManipulationsView**. Is this an Activity.? and please post the entire code. Is your class extending the Activity class.?

Comment: ImageManipulationsView is a class and it extends SampleCvViewBase which you can find here: http://pastebin.com/vwdyzhTp The full code of my app is here: http://pastebin.com/nHR3piui The problem is within the lines 185 and 195 Sorry for the overal mess in the code, I'm a beginner in Android programming and my app is a modification of the sample Image-manipulations from OpenCV4Android

Answer (score 0):

In Android design standards your code is a bit wrong.

But it looks like you can't 'see' the `context` variable from this class.

In your `ImageManipulationsView` class change the `context` variable to public.

```
 public Context context;
```

Comment: The whole app crashes after changing the variable to public.